# Treemap with Multiple Series

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I am trying to create TreeMap with multiple series, the series are getting plotted on the graph with both series clubbed together, but I want only one series to be displayed at a time. Basically legand can be used but for treemap it's showing values.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/arv9k205/) I am trying to work on[image]

**JavaScript files used**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The treemap should be updated as per the series selected.

**Highchart Bound Using**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    series: [{
    name:"Series 1",
        stack: 'aeroplanes',
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'A -Series 1',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 'B -Series 1',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'C -Series 1',
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 'D -Series 1',
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 'E -Series 1',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 'F -Series 1',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 'G -Series 1',
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    },
    // Second Series    
    {
       name:"Series 2",
        type: 'treemap',
        stack: 'aeroplanes2',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        visible:true,
        data: [{
            name: 'AA -Series 2',
            value: 16,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'BB -Series 2',
            value: 26,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Cc -Series 2',
            value: 14,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Dd -Series 2',
            value: 13,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Ee -Series 2',
            value: 12,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Ff -Series 2',
            value: 12,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Gg -Series 2',
            value: 11,
            colorValue: 2
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    },
      plotOptions: {
      treemap: {
        stacking: 'percent'
      }
    },
});
```

Comment: To sum up: you want a legend that will toggle the visibility of both series (e.g. *Series 1* is visible, *Series 2* is not; clicking on any of theirs legend items will cause that *Series 1* will hide and *Series 2* will show up)?

Comment: @KamilKulig Yes exactly as you understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `showInLegend` equals to `false` for treemap series - it needs to be enabled manually. In `legendItemClick` event I handled series visibility toggling:

```
  plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      showInLegend: true,
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          this.chart.series.forEach((s) => s.setVisible());
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0n49vv74/

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.treemap.events.legendItemClick
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.treemap.showInLegend
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Perfect, Exactly what I needed. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: How can I make this look like this, have different color axis for different set for series. http://prntscr.com/hym0z7

Comment: I did manage to have the prntscr.com/hym0z7  solved, now stuck with coloraxis,

Comment: It's possible to have only one color axis per chart in Highcharts.

Comment: The color across all point are of same, I need it based on min and max values. as in the http://prntscr.com/hym0z7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197130/coloraxis-with-highchart-not-working-as-expected-with-different-set-of-library is what I meant.

Comment: Nice idea but your algorithm is in fact wrong! it just works when you have two series. You have to use `s.setVisible(false); return true;` in order to toggle series correctly